# jQuery run through $(window).resize function only once on resize

Tags: jquery, resize, each

Having trouble taking the current height and making that the width on resize, then setting the new height to 8px. Because of the resize it takes the 8px value and then resets the height to the new 8px value. Please help.

```
$(window).resize(function() {

    if (Modernizr.mq('(max-width: 775px)')){
        $(".scores li a > div").each(function(index, value){
            var scoreHeight = $(this).height();
            $(this).width(scoreHeight);
            $(this).height("8px");
        });

    }
});
<ul>
<li class="self-awareness active">
    <a href="#self-awareness">
        <span>Self Awareness</span><span class="score"> - 400</span>
        <div style="height: 400px;">
            <div class="image"></div>
        </div>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="values">
    <a href="#values">
        <span>Values</span><span class="score"> - 348</span>
        <div style="height: 348px;">
            <div class="image"></div>
        </div>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="integrated-life">
    <a href="#integrated-life">
        <span>Integrated Life</span><span class="score"> - 208</span>
        <div style="height: 208px;">
            <div class="image"></div>
        </div>
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: This example is too narrow, it is hard to answer without a related DOM structure because it would require each potential answerer to recreate the element structure. Include your DOM structure in order to make this question answerable.

Comment: Do you want to enter in the `if` statement just once after the media query succeeds?

Comment: ok I added in the html that goes with the js. Basically I need it to run through the each function only once on the resize. When it runs through one time, the correct heights of each div is now the width. When it runs through the second and X times it changes the width to 8 px. So yes @komos, i would like for it to run through the if only once, but once it meets the if statement not once the page is done resizing. Thanks for the help